# How to Multiple screen size Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, size, screen

My app is sizing for all screens, but it didn't happen become for this model:

HUAWEI - SNE-LX1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you've created a different activity_main.xml file for each screen size.

The device you are referring to is of xxhdpi screen density. So, you will have to edit activity_main.xml(xxhdpi) file to see your layout change in this specific device.

If the other files are used and shown correctly in devices with other screen densities then  this file should also work with this device. So, try to edit this file and see if your changes are reflected on screen. Also, try rebuilding your project and restarting your emulator in case something has gone wrong there.

Comment: Thanks thanasis, that's how I try